# train_test_split: ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, mse

I'm currently trying to calculate the Mean Squared Error of a particular polynomial regression model. However, when I run `train_test_split` I get an error message:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here's the code I have written:

```
def mse(X, y, degree, model):
    X_train, y_train = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.6, random_state=10)
    train_errors = []
    for m in range(1, len(X_train)):
        model.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])
        mse = train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], y_train_predict))
    return mse
```

I'm unsure why I'm getting this error or what I can change up to make the code work! Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) also returns the test sample:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.6, random_state=10)
```